# Insert into sql server database error

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to insert data into the database, but I am getting an error when I click the button insert.

This is the error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There are more columns in the INSERT 
statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES 
clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.
```

I would like your help if you can figure out the problem.

This is my insertion code

```
    private void insertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
    try {
        db.connect();
        db.stm=db.con.createStatement();
        java.sql.Date date1 = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser1.getDate().getTime());
           int result=db.stm.executeUpdate("insert into Blood_Test_Result" +"(DID,D_Name,Weight,HBsAG,HIV,VDRL,HCV,Malaria,Blood_Type,Blood_Status,LTID,LT_Name,Date)" 
                   +"values('"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
                   + "'"+jTextField1.getText()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()+"','"+jComboBox4.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
                   + "'"+jComboBox5.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
                   + "'"+jComboBox7.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jComboBox8.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'"
                   + "'"+jComboBox9.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jComboBox10.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
                   + "'"+jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jTextField2.getText()+"','"+date1+"')");
        if(result>0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data has been saved succesfully");               
        }
        else 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "no data has been saved"); 
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BloodTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. **Stop concatenating strings to build your queries.  Use prepared statements!** 2. The error message is extremely clear about the issue... I don't know what's confusing about it.  You are explicitly saying you want to `INSERT` 13 columns, and only providing 12.

Comment: Could you print out the SQL statement your're trying to execute and share it with us?

Comment: My friend bobby tables loves code like this. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 4):

The error is clear you are using 13 column in .

```
(BTRID,DID,D_Name,Weight,HBsAG,HIV,VDRL,HCV,Malaria,Blood_Type,Blood_Status,LTID,LT_Name)
```

But you set 12 value in values :

```
values(....)
```

So check your query step by step and make sure that you are using the correct columns.

---

My answer is for this important part, don't set your attributes like this, instead use PreparedStatement to avoid syntax error and SQL Injection :

```
String query = "insert into Blood_Test_Result" + "(BTRID, DID ,D_Name, "
        + "Weight, HBsAG, HIV, VDRL, HCV, Malaria, Blood_Type, Blood_Status, LTID,LT_Name)"
        + "values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {

    insert.setString(1, jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString());
    insert.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
    ...

    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: SORRY, i posted the wrong data this is the actual data

Comment: what did you mean @YusufMohamed ?

Comment: could you please  look at the code again because i updated it.

Comment: you will find the same problem if u look the updated code and i dont know what the solution is

Comment: @YusufMohamed this is not possible, did you tried using preparedStatement ? like i mention in my answer?

Comment: i got it, it was just a comma missing thanks for trying to help

Comment: you are welcome @YusufMohamed if that help you don't forgot to accept the answer

Answer (score -1):

The error is very clear :

You have more Columns in your statment than values!

```
      (BTRID,DID,D_Name,Weight,HBsAG,HIV,VDRL,HCV,Malaria,Blood_Type,Blood_Status,LTID,LT_Name)
```

This are 13 columns and you have

```
jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
               + "'"+jTextField1.getText()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()+"','"+jComboBox4.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
               + "'"+jComboBox5.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
               + "'"+jComboBox7.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jComboBox8.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'"
               + "'"+jComboBox9.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jComboBox10.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
               + "'"+jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jTextField2.getText()+
```

only 12 values so remove  colmun and it ( but the correct ;-) ) and it should work

Comment: This is just perpetuating sql injection. This needs to be parameterized to be considered a viable answer.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the error because i was missing a comma between two columns.

```
private void insertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
    try {
        db.connect();
        db.stm=db.con.createStatement();
        java.sql.Date date1 = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser1.getDate().getTime());
           int result=db.stm.executeUpdate("insert into Blood_Test_Result" +"(DID,D_Name,Weight,HBsAG,HIV,VDRL,HCV,Malaria,Blood_Type,Blood_Status,LTID,LT_Name,Date)" 
                   +"values('"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
                   + "'"+jTextField1.getText()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()+"','"+jComboBox4.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
                   + "'"+jComboBox5.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
                   + "'"+jComboBox7.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jComboBox8.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
                   + "'"+jComboBox9.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jComboBox10.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',"
                   + "'"+jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+jTextField2.getText()+"','"+ date1 +"')");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "insert successful");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
    }
    fill();
    clear();

}
```

Thanks all for the help

Comment: This is not a good solution, because your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, which is a giant security hole. Follow the [suggestion by YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330401/466862) to use a prepared statement.